# Convert bash line to use in perl

Tags: apache, perl, bash, awk

How would I go about converting the following bash line into perl?  Could I run the system() command, or is there a better way?  I'm looking for perl to print out access per day from my apache access_log file.

In bash:

```
awk '{print $4}' /etc/httpd/logs/access_log | cut -d: -f1 | uniq -c
```

Prints the following:

```
632 [27/Apr/2014
156 [28/Apr/2014
```

Comment: Hey, that's not really Bash `:D`.

Comment: +1 `awk` is an independent language. `gawk` is an independent program. `cut` and `uniq` are independant commands ;)

Answer (score 6):

```
awk '{print $4}' /etc/httpd/logs/access_log | cut -d: -f1 | uniq -c
```

```
perl -lane'
    ($val) = split /:/, $F[3];      # First colon-separated elem of the 4th field
    ++$c{$val};                     # Increment number of occurrences of val
    END { print for map { "$c{$_} $_" } keys %c }  # Print results in no order
' access.log
```

Switches:

- `-l` automatically appends a newline to the print statement.
- `-l` also removes the newlines from lines read by `-n` (and `-p`).
- `-a` splits the line on whitespace into the array `@F`.
- `-n` loops over the lines of the input but does not print each line.
- `-e` execute the given script body.

Answer (score 3):

Your original command translated to a Perl one-liner:

```
perl -lane '($k) = $F[3] =~ /^(.*?):/; $h{$k}++ }{ print "$h{$_}\t$_" for keys %h' /etc/httpd/logs/access_log
```

Comment: @Virushunter, Because Perl literally surrounds the code with `LINE: while (<>) { ... }`

Comment: @Virushunter `}{` is **THE** `END` block. You can read more about special operators [here](http://search.cpan.org/~book/perlsecret-1.008/lib/perlsecret.pod)

Comment: cool, never knew about these ... I wonder how many more are waiting to be hunted down. Thank you for the link

Answer (score 1):

You can change all your commands to one from:

```
awk '{print $4}' /etc/httpd/logs/access_log | cut -d: -f1 | uniq -c
```

to

```
awk '{split($4,a,":");b[a[1]]++} END {for (i in b) print b[i],i}' /etc/httpd/logs/access_log
```